# Bootstrap's Modal Does Not Fade

Tags: pug, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a modal using Bootstrap v3.3.4. It does not appear when I use the class "modal fade" and click on the  tag, but it appears when I write in "modal in". I would like the modal to fade in and out on a click. Any ideas or files I should look into?

```
head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
body
    a(href='#', data-toggle='modal', role='button', data-target='#modalPassword') Change Password
    div(id='modalPassword', class='modal fade', tabindex='-1', role='dialog')
        div(class='modal-dialog')
            div(class='modal-content')
                div(class='modal-header')
                    button(type='button', class='close', data-dismiss='modal')&times;
                    h4(class='modal-title') Change Password
```

This is the code that I know my modal is working properly:

```
body
    a(href='#', data-toggle='modal', role='button', data-target='#modalPassword') Change Password
    div(id='modalPassword', class='modal in', tabindex='-1', role='dialog')
        // More code here
```

And my personal CSS:

```
.modal.in{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure from spaces of tags and space between `button` and   `&times;`

`button(type='button', class='close', data-dismiss='modal') &times;`

code work correctly with me after you add this changes

```
html 
    head
        title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    body

        a(href='#', data-toggle='modal', role='button', data-target='#modalPassword') Change Password
        div(id='modalPassword', class='modal fade', tabindex='-1', role='dialog')
            div(class='modal-dialog')
                div(class='modal-content')
                    div(class='modal-header')
                        button(type='button', class='close', data-dismiss='modal') &times;
                        h4(class='modal-title') Change Password
        script(type='text/javascript', src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help; it works properly now. All I was missing were the two scripts at the bottom.